# Creating a Django object with field values from a SELECT equivalent

Tags: django, django-models, sql-insert

I am trying to figure out how to reproduce the following using Django - anyone help?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (table2_id, a_field)
SELECT table2.id as table2_id, table3.a_field
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 ON
table3.table2_id == table2.id
WHERE table2.id = 123
```

If I've got this correct (not my original query ;-) ), this is doing the following:

- Creating an entry in `table1` where...
- a field named `table2_id` will match the `id` of a row in `table2` and
- a field named `a_field` will match the same named field in `a_field` in a row of `table3` and
- the `table2`/`table3` objects from which these values are read are identified by a shared `table2.id`/`table3.table_id2` relationship and also the `table2` `id` being `123`.

I don't see how such "calculated" field values can be passed to a `create()` or `get_or_create()` style command.  It this perhaps possible using `Q()` objects?

Answer (score 0):

Django model is an ORM framework.
In ORM way, you need

1. get table2Entity
2. construct a new table1Entity with table2Entity and related table3Entity values
3. save the table1Entity

   ```
   def batch_save_entity2():
       entity2 = Table2Entity.objects.get('123')
       entity1 = Table1Entity()
       entity1.table2_id = entity2.id
       entity1.a_field = entity2.entity3.a_field
       entity1.save()
   ```

or just execute sql [directly without ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('''
INSERT INTO table1 (table2_id, a_field)
SELECT table2.id as table2_id, table3.a_field
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 ON
table3.table2_id == table2.id
WHERE table2.id = 123''')
```